# How to install the "Apache Commons Math" library in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I had two questions about the "Apache Commons Math" library:

## 1. This library is based on java language. Is it possible to use it in kotlin?

If it can be used in Kotlin:

## 2.What is the installation method?

This is the link to download the latest version of this library : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi . I downloaded all these 4 files that are in the link, but there is no .jar file in any of them, on the other hand, I searched all over the internet, but I did not find its implementation code...

I have a basic need to use this library... Thank you for guiding me

I downloaded all these 4 files that are in the link, but there is no .jar file in any of them, on the other hand, I searched all over the internet, but I did not find its implementation code...

Comment: "I downloaded all these 4 files that are in the link, but there is no .jar file in any of them,". **Wrong** commons-math4-4.0-beta1-bin.tar.gz contains multiple jar files.

Comment: Which one should I use to add the library to the project? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin in general is built on the same underlying bytecode as java is, so all java libraries work on kotlin, and vice versa. As for installing, I recommend a build tool like [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to manage your project. IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA have full support for it, and it can work with kotlin.

To add to that, IDEA also gives you the option to generate a full gradle-using kotlin project, so I really recommend using IDEA with gradle to manage your dependencies.